# use javascript to make element take turns to appear

Tags: javascript

So I have two element `first` and `second`; I'm trying to let them take turns to appear; I have following code;

```
  setTimeout(setInterval(function(){
    $(".first").hide();
    $(".second").show();
  },20000),10000)

  setTimeout(setInterval(function(){
    $(".first").show();
    $(".second").hide();
  },20000),0)
```

it seems these codes doesn't work, can someone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found an alternative:

```
var d=0;
  setInterval(function(){
    if(d==0){
      d=1
      $(".first").hide();
      $(".second").show();
    }else if(d==1){
      d=0
      $(".first").show();
      $(".second").hide();
    }
  },10000)
```

Comment: Did you see the second block of code I proposed in my answer?  It is more compact than this.  Similar concept (using a flag to alternate), but uses less code.

Answer (score 0):

Your `setTimeout()` callbacks need to be actual function references like `function() {setInterval(...)}`.  The way you had it, you were executing the `setInterval()` immediately and then passing the results to `setTimeout()` which was doing nothing:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  setInterval(function(){
    $(".first").hide();
    $(".second").show();
},20000),10000);
```

---

But, there is a much better way to implement this with only a single timer:

```
(function() {
    var flag = true;
    setInterval(function() {
        flag = !flag;
        $(".first")[flag ? "hide" : "show"]();
        $(".second")[flag ? "show" : "hide"]();
    }, 10000);
})();
```

Or, if you set the hide/show state opposite initially, then you can just use jQuery's `.toggle()` to reverse the visibility:

```
    $(".first").show();
    $(".second").hide();
    setInterval(function() {
        $(".first").toggle();
        $(".second").toggle();
    }, 10000);
```

Comment: @XiaoQu - I added another example using jQuery's `.toggle()`.